# How is "<" in HTML handled by browsers?

Tags: html, w3c

In the following snippet, < gets rendered as expected in Firefox 37.0.2 and I have seen the same in many other modern browsers as well.  Is this textarea specification valid HTML5? Ideally shouldn't it be &lt; by escaping the "<"

```
<html>
<textarea>
Hello World <
</textarea>
</html>
```

How does the HTML parsers distinguish between a Tag Open and "<"? Most browsers do a lot to handle errors automatically by guessing, is this one such case?

The reason I am interested in this is because when we use WYSIWYG editors in Web Apps - we save the HTML from the editors source mostly. When we Template it back for the frontend, this behaviour makes it is not mandatory to HTML Quote stuff from the backend. It works without HTML Quoting but it can cause undesired effects like freezing / infinite loop's atleast with the TinyMCE Editor's 3.5.8 version.

Comment: It's not proper HTML, no, as the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) will tell you. As to how browsers will handle it, that's easy to find out by trying it out - there's not going to be a rule. What is your specific situation, why are you asking this?

Comment: I did and it works in Firefox 37.0.2 as mentioned. But is it valid? The reason I ask is that we bump into issues with TinyMCE editor. The fact that this works makes developers avoid using the proper HTML quoting for stuff that gets saved in the editor.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed just guessing. The proper way to use literal `<` in HTML is to use `&lt;` (and `&gt;` for `>`).

That said, `textarea` is a bit specific in that it can never contain any other HTML elements - so the parser can be sure you meant literal `<` and not a starting tag. Of course, it breaks down for `</textarea>` :)

From HTML 4 specification:

Section 5.3.2:

> Authors wishing to put the "<" character in text should use "<" (ASCII decimal 60) to avoid possible confusion with the beginning of a tag (start tag open delimiter). Similarly, authors should use ">" (ASCII decimal 62) in text instead of ">" to avoid problems with older user agents that incorrectly perceive this as the end of a tag (tag close delimiter) when it appears in quoted attribute values.

So it's not *necessary* for HTML 4, but it's still good practice. And of course, XHTML and / or HTML 5 may be a bit more strict.

HTML specification is actually quite non-specific in a lot of things, which goes a long way to ensuring the browsers are incompatible with each other in (more or less) subtle ways. Your best bet is not to rely on all the things HTML *allows*, but only on those that are very explicit and specific. The reason is quite simple - two browsers can be 100% fully compliant with the HTML specification, and still process the same HTML in ways that make it completely useless.

Comment: Thats right, we shouldn't rely on things that HTML allows. But hard to enforce this among developers who are happy to make it work by any means including yours truly :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say without insight in the actual code, but common HTML parsers try to find the closing tag when an opening tag is encountered.

All characters that to not resemble to an element are printed as if they were escaped **if you are lucky!** This is certainly true for elements that only allow text, like the `<textarea>` in your sample.

This is not valid HTML and should be avoided obviously.

Answer (score 2):

The Mozilla HTML parser will ignore any any 'less than' angle bracket not immediately succeeded by a valid tag type.
Any white space character (space, tab, newline etc.) renders the bracket 'not a tag'.
Also anything inside a textarea can only ever be text.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the validity, the HTML5 spec defines the precise parsing rules completely.

When the tree construction rules encounter a `<textarea>` tag, the tokeniser gets switched into the [RCDATA state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#rcdata-state)

In that state, if the tokeniser encounters a `<` character it switches to the [RCDATA less-than sign state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#rcdata-less-than-sign-state)

In that state, unless the next character is a `/`, it treats the `<` simply as a `<` and continues. Otherwise, the tokeniser switches to the [RCDATA end tag open state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#rcdata-end-tag-open-state)

And so on, with the objective of allowing the parser to detect the `</textarea>` tag, but passing everything else through as text.

There is no "guessing" involved, and all modern browsers, including IE since IE10 follow these rules.